Get document ID from LDA output R
I'm trying to do LDA over two very large corpus of documents.
I need to compare the LDA output (planning to use the Kullback-Leibler similarity measure) across time for each pair of documents. Therefore, at some point, I need to "merge" my documents by time.
output_directory= "fed documents/"
names_files=list.files(output_directory)

## FIRST GO WITH MINUTES

## MINUTES
# 5) MINUTES
minutes_names <- names_files[grepl("(minutes|histmin|moa|ropa)", names_files, ignore.case = TRUE)]

minutes=list()

for (this_gb in minutes_names) {
  this_books_path=paste(output_directory,this_gb, sep="/")
  this_book=pdf_text(this_books_path)
  
  minutes[[this_gb]]=this_book
  remove(this_book)
  
}


mins_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(minutes))
mins_corpus <- tm_map(mins_corpus, tolower)
mins_corpus <- tm_map(mins_corpus, removePunctuation)
mins_corpus <- tm_map(mins_corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
mins_corpus <- tm_map(mins_corpus, stemDocument, language = "english")
mins_corp_matrix=DocumentTermMatrix(mins_corpus)

# GET THE LDA MEASURE
mins_lda=LDA(mins_corp_matrix, k=30, control=list( seed=141096)) # ACOSTA USES 30
mins_topics=tidy(mins_lda, matrix="gamma") # GET THE PROBABILITIES BY DOCUMENT AND TOPIC



This is my first corpus. It's basically the set of minutes, minutes of policy actions and record of policy actions from the Fed's historical archive.
The second set is similarly set up, and consists of speeches given by the chair of the Fed.
output_directory= "fed chair speeches/"
speeches_files <- list.files(output_directory)
speeches_chairs_fed=list()

for(this_speech in speeches_files){
  this_speech_path=paste(output_directory,this_speech, sep="/")
  this_speech=pdf_text(this_speech_path)
  
  if (grepl("\\b(high school|opening|closing|education|summit|school|club)\\b", this_speech, ignore.case = TRUE)) {
    # Skip this speech and move to the next
    next
  }
  
  speeches_chairs_fed[[this_speech]]
  
}



speech_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(speeches_chairs_fed))
speech_corpus <- tm_map(speech_corpus, tolower)
speech_corpus <- tm_map(speech_corpus, removePunctuation)
speech_corpus <- tm_map(speech_corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
speech_corpus <- tm_map(speech_corpus, stemDocument, language = "english")
speech_corp_matrix=DocumentTermMatrix(speech_corpus)

# GET THE LDA MEASURE
speech_lda=LDA(speech_corp_matrix, k=30, control=list( seed=141096)) # ACOSTA USES 30
speeches_topics=tidy(speech_lda, matrix="gamma") # GET THE PROBABILITIES BY DOCUMENT AND TOPIC

I have both sets now, and I need to get a way to merge (either the output of LDA, or the lists) by a common date.
That is, I have two desired outputs:

LDA output (the gamma and beta matrices, using LDA notation) for a pair of speech-minutes in a given date
a list that merges, by date, the speeches and the minutes, and then applies LDA. I know I could merge the two lists rather easily, but the problem I see in this approach is that I need to apply LDA to each speech and minute separately and compute the gamma and beta matrices for each, not jointly.

